# Node JS Express same thing for route GET and POST

Tags: node.js, express

I am working with nodejs/express. I want to do the same thing for a route, for GET and POST http requests.

I am doing this:

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // Some code
  });

  app.post('/', function(req, res) {
     // Same code
  });
```

Is there a way to refactor get and post in the same callback ?

Thanks

Comment: why not just use one or the other exclusively? having POST do the same thing as GET is not the proper usage of the two HTTP methods.

Comment: It is for the login page: When you first come on the login page, you come with a GET request. When you type a bad login, you stay on the same page, but this is a POST request

Comment: Just redirect the user on a bad request...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Or you can use `all`, if your site doesn't use any other methods in particular:

```
app.all('/', handler)
```

Answer (score 13):

This seems like a very odd requirement. If the behavior is exactly the same just specify one function to handle both:

```
 function myHandler(req, res) {
   // Some code
 }

 app.get('/', myHandler);
 app.post('/', myHandler);
```

Comment: Your a better typist than me !

Comment: Inside the myHandler you can test what method was used by `if(req.method === 'GET') ...`

Comment: You can use `router.route('/').get().post()` in order to avoid dupe path.

Answer (score 4):

A bit old question but still facing today.

If you want to expose the api for all method with the same handler:

```js
function sameHandler(req, res) {
  // do something here
}
app.all('/', sameHandler);
```

If just wanna use the same route but with different handlers:

```js
function getHandler(req, res) {
  // do something here
}
function postHandler(req, res) {
  // do something here
}
function deleteHandler(req, res) {
  // do something here
}
app.route('/').get(getHandler).post(postHandler).delete(deleteHandler);
```